# Multiple submit button in one form

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a controller with request mapping and view where located two buttons "save" and "delete", but they don't do anything. I tried to debug it< but nothing

I used a Spring mvc with thymleaf, I tried a lot of variants, for example : action, individual controller for it, but nothing

```
<h:form method="post" data-th-action="@{/admin/edit-page/edit}" 
   th:object="${product}">
            <button type="submit" name="action" 
           value="save">save</button>
           <button type="submit" name="action" 
            value="cancel">cancel</button>

</h:form>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/edit-page/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=save")
    public ModelAndView save() {

        return null;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/edit-page/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=cancel")
    public ModelAndView cancel() {

        return null;   
}
```

I want to perform an action based on what button was pressed

Answer (score 1):

In the controller methods, your model parameter is missing.

try like bellow

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/edit-page/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=save")
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute Product product) {
      //assuming Product is your class
        return null;
    }


// same for delete
```